# Can we merge the tag [database-trigger] into the tag [trigger]?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tagging, tag-synonyms, retag-request

I think the tags [trigger](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/trigger) and [database-trigger](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/database-trigger) means the same thing.

I suggest we merge [database-trigger](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/database-trigger) into the tag [trigger](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/trigger).

Answer (score 5):

Yes this seems like a good idea.

Comment: Huh, I was expecting to see some DDL triggers on the [database-trigger] tag...

Comment: Yeah me too. There is [tag:ddl-trigger] but that doesn't seem very popular. Shrug.